# One page site navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-findcond navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img alt="null">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#products">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#test">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#order">Order</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="products">
  <div></div>
</section>
```

I change my section `class="products"` to section `id="products"`, and when I click it, nothing happen.

The reason why I used id is because the active navbar is not showing. I'm using findcond navbar bootstrap.

Comment: Do you know html and css ? or new to that?

Comment: What is `findcond navbar bootstrap`?

Comment: findcond snippet :) bootsnip.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
<section id="products" class ="products">
```

Since I don't know about back-end operations, cannot sure about it. I trust some operations are done by that css class `products`.